# What differences are there between "famous" and "famed"?

Tags: differences, adjectives

We sometimes see both cases, such as "the famous church" and "the famed church". In what situation or objective do you use "famous" and "famed"? Please advise.

Comment: They're close synonyms, but 'famed' probably invokes the personal involvement more (we're so familiar with 'famous' that we probably focus on the referent more than the large number of people who know of it).

Comment: You should include references to dictionary entries for both of these words. This provides a good starting point for answers; the dictionary entries should explain the basic meanings of each word, and because of that, the answers can focus on explaining further nuances rather than just repeating the information you'd find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

**famed**

[etymonline etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=famed&allowed_in_frame=0)

> "much talked about," 1530s, past participle adjective from fame "spread abroad, report" (v.), c. 1300, from Old French *famer*, from fame "reputation, renown" (see fame (n.)).

As you can see, since *famed* derives from a past participle, its usage is more specialized than *famous*, as *famed* is best used for historical places, events, old/deceased people who were once famous. It's used to give respect to past accomplishments. On the other hand, *famous* is a more versatile option because it can be used to describe both past and present fame, however it is best served when describing a presently famous thing.

**famous**

[etymonline etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=famous&allowed_in_frame=0)

> late 14c., "celebrated in public report, renowned, well-known" also "notorious, infamous," from Anglo-French famous, Old French fameus (Modern French fameux), from Latin famosus "much talked of, renowned," often "infamous, notorious, of ill repute," from fama (see fame (n.)).

As you can see, "*celebrated in public report*" suggests that the subject in question is *presently* famous.

---

Usage in literature:

*Devon, Its Moorlands, Streams and Coasts* by Rosalind Northcote

> "Tiverton **was famed in early days** for its trade in wool."

*Encyclopaedia Britannica, 11th Edition, Volume 7, Slice 6* by Various

> "The author **at once became famous**, although he had not, even yet, completed his fifteenth year."

As you can see here, **famed** wouldn't work in the second sentence, but **famous** would work in both sentences, albeit *famed* is better suited in the first because of its past-tense-niche nature.

---

Another difference is that *famed* sometimes indicates a smaller degree of *fame* than *famous* does. For instance, if someone in a niche field who was only recognized within that field were to die, you wouldn't describe him as *famous*, but *famed*. It's more respectful.

A simple Google search of the term [' "famed" dies '](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22famed%22&oq=%22f&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i65l2.4266j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22famed%22+dies&tbas=0) shows that the word *famous* wouldn't be a good substitute for this specific case. 99% of these people the average person has no clue of, so *famed* is a nice alternative to pay respect while not commiting hyperbole.

> Bill Cunningham, **Famed** Street Fashion Photographer, Dies At 87
>
> Kimbo Slice, **Famed** Mixed Martial Artist, Dies in Florida at 42
>
> **Famed** Cancer Theorist Dr. Alfred G. Knudson Jr. Dies at 93
>
> Frank Lloyd Wright Dies; **Famed** Architect Was 89
>
> 'Future Shock' author and **famed** futurist Alvin Toffler dies at 87
>
> **Famed** river guide George Wendt dies at 74
>
> **Famed** Pakistan philanthropist Edhi dies in Karachi
>
> Steve Pisanos Dies at 96: **Famed** Decorated WWII Fighter Pilot
>
> Vic Kleman, **famed** Kennywood coaster enthusiast, dies at 83

---

In summary, you wouldn't use *famed* for something that became *instantly famous*, [as evidenced by this Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=became+famed%2Cbecame+famous&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecame%20famed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecame%20famous%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

---

[Google search for "instantly famous":](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22instantly+famous%22&oq=%22instantly+famous%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4449j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#) 47,800 results

[Google search for "instantly famed":](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22instantly+famous%22&oq=%22instantly+famous%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4449j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22instantly+famed%22&nfpr=1) 387 results

---

Answer (score 0):

Famed is a synonym of famous.
The difference between famed and famous is that famed is having fame; famous or noted while famous is well known.

Sydney is famous/famed for its opera house

[http://the-difference-between.com/famous/famed][1]

Comment: Please provide references to substantiate your answer - otherwise it could be merely your opinion rather than a definitive answer.  Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).